# File Uploads via Dropbox Api V2

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

Previously I was using the **Dropbox API V1** within my web app to upload files my dropbox account. Please note that the app uses only one dropbox account (mine) to upload files.

**So Previously:**

1. I created an app on the dropbox developers console
2. Generated my token from the developers console
3. Hard coded that token into my server to upload all file to a specific folder within my Dropbox.

This worked perfectly before but as the dropbox API v1 has been deprecated it does not work anymore.

**Dropbox V1 Code:**

```
function fileupload(content) {
 request.put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/my_reports/report.pdf', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'TOKEN HERE',
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            },
            body: content
        }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("File uploaded to dropbox successfully!");
                fs.unlink(temp_dir + 'report.pdf', function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else {
                        console.log("file deleted from server!");
                    }
                })
                request.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/shares/auto/MY_reports/report.pdf' + '?short_url=false', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'TOKEN HERE'
                    }
                }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Shared link 2 ' + JSON.parse(httpResponse.body).url);

                    }
                });

            }
        });
     }
```

**Dropbox V2 Code:**

```
function fileupload(content) {
 request.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload/my_reports', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'TOKEN HERE',
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            },
            body: content
        } ......... (rest of the code is similar to above)
```

**Issue:**

What I have tried does not work. I can't seem to upload a file to my dropbox account from within my app. **I have tried re-generating my TOKEN from the Dropbox App console but no luck.**

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I updated my code to similar structure for v2 of the API but still unable to resolve it.

```
 request.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN',
                    'Dropbox-API-Arg': {"path": "/Homework","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false},
                    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
                    //'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
                },
                body: content
            } .... similar code
```

Comment: API v2 works differently than API v1. For example, the file path isn't passed on the URL itself, so you'll need to update your code to use the API v2 style. There's an example in the documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload Also, make sure you check the response body for errors.

Comment: @Greg please see my updated question.

Comment: That looks closer, but it still doesn't match the documentation. For example, you should be setting `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: In any case, check the response body. It should have a more helpful error message.

Comment: @Greg I tried using the octet-stream content type but no luck. Also it doesn't give me any error message. There has be to be mistake I'm making somewhere.

Comment: As long as you make the request, you should get some sort of error or response. You'll need to inspect that for more information. Or, more ideally, use a library, e.g., as shown in [asasq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495328/1305693).

Comment: @Greg Apologies my mistake I was not logging the response. I get this response `body: 'Unknown API function: "files/upload/".' ` The response contains a lot more data.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra trailing "/". Change the URL to `'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload'`.

Comment: @Greg If I could hug you right now. I would! Thanks for the help mate. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use existing nodejs dropbox packages, which hides abstraction of an authentication process, etc. under the hood.

Check official [dropbox-sdk-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) or try my tiny package [dropbox-v2-api](https://github.com/adasq/dropbox-v2-api). Quick example:

```
const dropboxV2Api = require('dropbox-v2-api');

//create session
const dropbox = dropboxV2Api.authenticate({
    token: 'TOKEN HERE'
});

//create upload stream
const uploadStream = dropbox({
    resource: 'files/upload',
    parameters: {
        path: '/dropbox/path/to/file.txt'
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    // upload completed
});

//use nodejs stream
fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.txt').pipe(uploadStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is also to use a SDK which abstracts over authentication. [CloudRail for Node.js](https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage;platformId=Nodejs;serviceIds=Dropbox;interfaceId=CloudStorage;interfaceFunctionId=CloudStorage-upload) could be very useful here. It's quite easy to use and works for other providers like OneDrive as well.

```
const cloudrail = require("cloudrail-si");

const service = new cloudrail.services.Dropbox(
    cloudrail.RedirectReceivers.getLocalAuthenticator(8082),
    "[Dropbox Client Identifier]",
    "[Dropbox Client Secret]",
    "http://localhost:8082/auth",
    "someState"
);

service.upload(
    "/myFolder/myFile.png",
    readableStream,
    1024,
    true,
    (error) => {
        // Check for potential error
    }
);
```

Here is also a [short article about the {“error”: “v1_retired”} issue](https://blog.cloudrail.com/how-to-solve-dropbox-error-v1_retired-for-the-dropbox-api/).