# Dropbox V2 file upload end point - invalid Content Type - dropbox-cor s-hack

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use the V2 end points for file upload. I believe the content headers are set right but I keep getting this error. Can anyone help please ?

```
const request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var apiArgs = '{ "path" : "/testfolder/Nespresso.zip", "mode" : "add", "autorename" : true, "mute" : false }' ;

var formData = {
    'data-binary': fs.createReadStream("F:\\Nespresso.zip")
};

const options = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ############',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': apiArgs
    },
    formData : formData
};

request.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', options, function(err, res, body) {
    //let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(body);
    if(res)
    console.log(res.statusCode);

    if(err)
    console.log(err);
});
```

Error on node :

Error in call to API function "files/upload": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "m
ultipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------298294176382492406791283"
.  Expecting one of "application/octet-stream", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cor
s-hack".
400

Comment: I hope this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494247/file-uploads-via-dropbox-api-v2/46495328#46495328

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether `data-binary` is valid `formData` property of request configuration object. See https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads.  What's more, Dropbox requires `application/octet-stream` type data instead of `multipart/form-data` as you have provided. How about:

```
const request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ############',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
            'path' : '/package.json'
        })
    }
};

const uploadStream = request.post(options, function(err, res, body) {
    //let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(body);
    if(res)
    console.log(res.statusCode);

    if(err)
    console.log(err);
});

fs.createReadStream('./package.json').pipe(uploadStream);
```

Comment: That's correct, the file data should be sent up in the request body, but the code in the question sends it as form data, causing `request` to set `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`. Another option is to put the file data in a `body` field (instead of `formData`) in the `options`.