# data-Binary in request nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox

I'm trying to upload a file to dropbox throug nodeJS.
This CURL request works.

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer myToken" \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary @fileName
```

I don't know how to translate it into javascript code.
Here's what I've accomplished so far:

```
    var request = require('request')
    var headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + dropboxToken,
        "Dropbox-API-Arg": {
                            "path": "/"+fileName, //nome sul drive
                            "mode": "add",
                            "autorename": true,
                            "mute": false
                            },
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    }
    var options = {
        url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    });
```

**How do I include the `data-binary` option in this request** in order to select the file to upload?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495328/1757378

Answer (score 1):

you can create a readstream and then pipe it to request with your current headers and options like-

```
fs.createReadStream('/path/to/youfile').pipe(request.post(options).on('end', (done) => { console.log('success') }));
```

Answer (score -1):

First, if you're trying to integrate with the Dropbox API in JavaScript, we recommend using the official Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK, as it will do most of the work for you:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the SDK, you can make the requests yourself. In this case, the `--data-binary` parameter is the `curl` parameter for supplying the data for the request to `curl`. `curl` then takes that data and puts it in the request body, which is the correct way to supply file data for [a Dropbox API v2 "content-upload" style endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats), such as [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload).

So, you should check the documentation for the HTTP client you're using for information on how to set the request body. It looks like you're using [the `request` node module](https://github.com/request/request), which appears to [take a `body` option, where you can put the request data](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback).

Comment: I tried to insert the body like this `var options = {
    url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
    headers: headers,
    body: '@'+'/myFile.txt'
}`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: The `@` syntax is just a way of specifying a local file to `curl`. That presumably doesn't apply to the node request module. From [the documentation for that](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback), you should supply the data as "`Buffer`, `String` or `ReadStream`".